# Drawing Map on two or more sheets without Overlays?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am producing a map for the forest management department. The map is about a forest station and has a strict scale of 1:10000 on AO paper size but my "station" is too large and cannot fit into one sheet/paper. If I produce it on two sheets there definitely an overlap 'where features are repeated in both sheets'.

Comment: Is this a related to the symbology you are having an issue  ?

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your help for answering my question. Turns out the methods suggested did not produce what I was looking for. All the same, I appreciate the help and am still looking forward to learn more. Nevertheless, I found the answer and I will upload it here. am just editing to provide a detailed methodology for anyone who might be experiencing the same problem.the solution is using the MapBooks extension for ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on your printer but one solution is to create a "double A0" sized map and let your printer do the tiling to print it on two single A0 sheet of paper.

Another way is to use the data driven page feature with two contiguous non overlapping polygon sized to exactly cover the area you want to print